# Function to write dataframe to SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have this function that takes in a dataframe and writes it to SQL as a table.

```
def insert(df):
    with connection.cursor as cur:
          cur.execute('''create tablaexyz.xyz
                         (ID integer,
                         first_name varchar(100),
                         last_name  varchar(100))''')
         df.values.to_list()
         cur.execute('''insert into xyz.xyz(?,?,?)''', df)
```

I would like to make this function dynamic to where I pass in the dataframe and it automatically creates the table based of the number of columns in the dataframe. For the datatypes, it would be nice to have something that creates the equivalent SQL column type based on the pandas column type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also, I am aware of pandas.to_sql.  This will not work for my purposes.  Would like something to organically create out of the code I already have that works.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

According to docs it should be even capable of creating tables.

Comment: not using sql alchemy, so don't have an engine.  Looking for an organic way of coding what I already have.

Answer (score 0):

Without reference to a specific RDBMS, it might be hard to "guess" the correct datatypes for all corner cases. On the other hand, e.g. DuckDB provides functionality to integrate pandas dataframes as queryable views (see section [efficient transfer](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python)).